# Hibernate One To One Bidirectional Not working

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, bidirectional

I am trying to make my code have a bidrectional relationship(One TO One) But apparently the code is not working.

here's the First Class.

```
public class User {


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_FK")
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    //Accessor methods and other stuff
}
```

and this is the second class

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="USER_PROFILE")
public class UserProfile{


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="UserProfile")
    private User user;
    //Accessor methods
}
```

Now when I run my code this exception error occurs

```
Unknown mappedBy in: org.test.myApp.User, referenced property unknown: org.test.myApp.User.UserProfile
```

Answer (score 3):

The field at the other side of the association is named `userProfile`, not `UserProfile`, so the mappedBy attribute must be set to `userProfile`.